# Only The 'Welcome to Bonfire' Screen Displays

Tags: config, bonfire

I tried Installing Bonifre on Xampp. It get's properly installed. But when I try to login into Admin Panel. It redirects back to the "Welcome Screen".

I have tried changing `$config['uri_protocol']` to other options provided in config file. But none of them Works. I followed the bonfire docs.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the session.php file in(bonfire\ci3\libraries\Session) with the following which is from an older version.
https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/blob/0.8.3/bonfire/ci3/libraries/Session/Session.php

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).